# Could you please explain why the remainder when the square of 49 is divided by the square root of 49 is 0?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Here is the original question,

**What is the remainder when the square of 49 is divided by the square root of 49?**

According to UKMT,

***Because 49 = 7×7, it follows both that $\sqrt 49$ = 7 and that 7 is a factor of 49.***

***There fore 7 is also a factor of $49^2$.***

***Hence the remainder when the square of 49 is divided by the square root of 49 is 0***

They also gave the investigation,

***1. Explain why it is true that for each positive integer n,***

***$(n^2)^2 ÷ \sqrt{n^2} =0$***

***2. Follow investigation 1, is the remainder still 0 in the case where n is a negative
integer?***

The answer I came up with was 343.

And I still don't get why it is true that the remainder is 0 in ***investigation 1.***

Could you please explain it in more detail, and if it's okay, please also explain ***investigation 2.***

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Because $n$ is a factor of $n^4$ ?

Comment: @samjoe Could explain more please?

Comment: Do you know the definition of a remainder?

Comment: $n^4=n^3\times n+0$ where the second term on RHS stands for the remainder when there is division by $n$. How did you get $343$?

Comment: Don't say $(n^2)^2÷\sqrt{n^2}=0$. That's not what "the remainder is $0$" means.

Answer (score 3):

I think you're confusing "remainder" with "quotient."  If you divide $49^2$ by $7$ the quotient is $343$.  The remainder is $0$.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're confusing the terms quotient and remainder lets try with an example. Find the quotient and remainder when $23$ is divided by $7$
$$23=\color{red}3\cdot 7+\color{blue}2$$
Now the red part is the quotient while the blue is the remainder now $$7^4=\color{red}{343}\cdot 7+\color{blue}0$$
The red part is equal to $343$ which is the quotient while the blue part is equal to $0$ which is the remainder.

Answer (score 0):

Just because $(\sqrt{n^2})^4=n^4$.

Comment: and then why 0?

Comment: By definition, the remainder is zero if and only if the number divides the other one.

In fact if you do $\frac{n^4}{n}=n^3+0$